# How to use vim-markdown :Toc: for documents with extension other than .md

Tags: filetype-markdown

When editing long markdown documents it is really good to be able to navigate in them with the `:Toc` option from [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown).

I also edit long .Rmd documents from vim (when the content is more about text than about R code). 
I have added the following to my ~/.vimrc:

```
let g:vim_markdown_auto_extension_ext = 'Rmd'
```

`:Toc` works fine in `.md` documents, but when I enter `:Toc` in a .Rmd document, I get the error: "E492: Not an editor command: Toc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vim-markdown documentation isn't really very clear about `g:vim_markdown_auto_extension_ext`, but that's actually about the extension it will add to URLs it builds from links in your markdown. It will default to `.md`, but you can override it here.

By default, it will only [recognize](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftdetect/markdown.vim) a few extensions such as `*.md`, `*.markdown` and a few others as being of type "markdown".

In order to accept `*.Rmd` as a markdown, you should add your own autocmd for it.

You can either create a new file under `~/.vim/ftdetect`, such as `~/.vim/ftdetect/Rmd.vim` with the line:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.Rmd set ft=markdown
```

Or you can add a new augroup block to your vimrc instead:

```
 augroup filetypedetect_markdown
   au!
   au BufRead,BufNewFile *.Rmd set ft=markdown
augroup END
```

Comment: I don't know R markdown, but `R.markdown` may be more appropriate

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks I'm now setting 2 file types as you suggested with `ft=rmd.markdown`. It makes it possible to use 2 plugins which expect different file types (1) [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) gives a table of content for files of type `markdown` and (2) [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) sends code chunks to R with `<localleader>cc` for files of type `rmd`.

Comment: @PaulRougieux nice, i’ve used similar approaches before. Very convenient

Comment: It works partly but it's not perfect because "vim-markdown" messes up the syntax highlight and autocomplete of 'Nvim-R". It's been reported in [issue 263](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/issues/263)